# Restarting a failed Spring (Boot) Batch job lauched by command line

Tags: spring-boot, spring-batch, resume

I know that there is a lot of questions and posts about this topic (besides the own Spring documentation), but I admit that I still didn't manage to figure out how do job restarts work.

First of all, I'm using Spring Boot for creating my batch program. The relevant parts of my pom.xml follow:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">

    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>2.2.1.RELEASE</version>
        <relativePath /> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>

    ...

    <dependencies>
        <!-- Spring -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-batch</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-configuration-processor</artifactId>
            <optional>true</optional>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>org.junit.vintage</groupId>
                    <artifactId>junit-vintage-engine</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.batch</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-batch-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>

        <!-- Databases -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.postgresql</groupId>
            <artifactId>postgresql</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <!-- Misc -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
            <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
            <optional>true</optional>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.google.guava</groupId>
            <artifactId>guava</artifactId>
            <version>23.0</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

</project>
```

The main class is annotated with @EnableBatchProcessing:

```
@SpringBootApplication
@EnableBatchProcessing
public class Migrator {

    public static void main( String[] args ) {
        SpringApplication.run( Migrator.class, args );
    }

}
```

And the Job, properly said, is configured as follows:

```
@Configuration
public class EnigmaPartitionedJobConfig {

    @Autowired
    private JobBuilderFactory jobBuilderFactory;

    ...

    @Bean
    public Job configureJob( @Qualifier( "constraintsTurnOffStep" ) Step constraintsTurnOffStep, 
                             @Qualifier( "constraintsTurnOnStep" ) Step constraintsTurnOnStep,
                             @Qualifier( "partitionerStep" ) Step partitionerStep ) {
        return jobBuilderFactory
                        .get( "migratorPartitionedJob" )
                        .incrementer( new RunIdIncrementer() )
                        .start( constraintsTurnOffStep )
                        .next( partitionerStep )
                        .next( constraintsTurnOnStep )
                        .build();
    }

    ...

}
```

So, the job is composed of three steps. The first and last ones are very simple. They just turn off and on, respectivelly, some constraints in the target database. The middle step is the core business. It reads an input file desbribing the source database, and applies a table based partition. That is, a copy of the migration step is run on a separate thread for each table of the source database:

```
    @Bean( "partitionerStep" )
    public Step partitionerStep( @Qualifier( "migrationAndAnonymizationStep" ) Step migrationAndAnonymizationStep, TaskExecutor taskExecutor ) {
        return stepBuilderFactory
                    .get( "partitionerStep" )
                    .partitioner( "migrationAndAnonymizationStep", new MultiTablePartitioner( this.model.getEntities() ) )
                    .step( migrationAndAnonymizationStep )
                    .taskExecutor( taskExecutor )
                    .gridSize( this.model.getEntitiesCount() )
                    .build();
    }
```

Finally, the migration step is configured as follows:

```
    @Bean( "migrationAndAnonymizationStep" )
    public Step migrationAndAnonymizationStep( MigrationAndAnonymizationReader reader, 
                                               MigrationAndAnonymizationProcessor processor, 
                                               MigrationAndAnonymizationWriter writer,  
                                               TaskExecutor taskExecutor ) {

        return stepBuilderFactory
                    .get( "migrationAndAnonymizationStep" )
                    .<Map<String, Object>, Map<String, Object>>chunk( 50 )
                    .reader( reader )
                    .processor( processor )
                    .writer( writer )
                    .taskExecutor( taskExecutor )
                    .throttleLimit( 1 )
                    .build();
    }
```

`MigrationAndAnonymizationReader` is basically a `JdbcCursorItemReader` with some configuration due to the partitioning, whereas `MigrationAndAnonymizationWriter` is basically a subclass of `FlatFileItemWriter` with some minor initialization, just like `MigrationAndAnonymizationReader`.

Job executions are run using command line:

```
$ java -jar migrator-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar --spring.profiles.active=[list of profiles] --migrator.source-username=XXX --migrator.source-password=XXX --migrator.target-username=XXX --migrator.target-password=XXX --spring.datasource.username=XXX --spring.datasource.password=XXX --migrator.model-path=[path to a specific input file]
```

My test for checking the restart functionality consists in running the job using a command like the previous one and, during the execution (it usually takes 2 mins to process the test database I'm using), I kill the process. Then, I execute the same command line and my expectation was that the job would restart, not executing finished steps and steps that didn't finish, start executing from the point they were before the failure. However, every time I attempt this test what I see is the job executing completely from the begining.

So, what am I missing here? What action, implementation or configuration is Spring Boot/Batch expecting from me?

Comment: What is the value of column , BATCH_JOB_EXECUTION.STATUS after **I kill the process** & before restart ? Is it `FAILED` or `STARTED` ?

Comment: ```STARTED```. I also tried to change it to ```FAILED``` both on the ```BATCH_JOB_EXECUTION``` and ```BATCH_STEP_EXECUTION```, but no success.

Comment: Changing the status to FAILED is not enough, you need to set the END_TIME to a non null as well. Does this fix your issue?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Spring Batch starts a new job because of this line:

```
.incrementer( new RunIdIncrementer() )
```

This generates a unique id for every run.

If you want to restart a job you have to make sure that the parameters for you pass to the job are the same. So you cannot use RunIdIncrementer

Comment: Makes sense Simon. I commented out this line and included one more parameter to the command line (--migrator.job-id=some id). In theory this should make the job think that I want a fresh run, but it I'm getting the error:  ```org.springframework.batch.core.repository.JobExecutionAlreadyRunningException: A job execution for this job is already running```. The job thinks that the new run is a second attempt of executing a previously failed job, even with the new parameter. Am I still missing something?

Comment: Please have a look at the docs: https://docs.spring.io/spring-batch/docs/current/reference/html/job.html#restartability

Comment: I'm sorry, it's not clear what part of the reference you indicated I should pay attention. My job is supposed to be restartable, so it doesn't have ```preventRestart()``` flag set. I understood that executing the job with an unique set of parameters should cause a complete and fresh run, regardless of past failed attempts. But this is not what is happening. Even removing the incrementer from the job configuration and adding a new parameter with unique value, spring batch still thinks that I'm trying to rerun a failed instance.

Comment: How do you start/restart the batch job? There is a restart method on the JobOperator

Comment: I'm just running the command line again, but adding a new parameter in the end. The point is the last job that really run didn't finish (I intentionally killed the process). Now I made the change you suggested, about the incrementer, and I would like the job to make a fresh run, ignoring the last job run (which failed). That is, in this case I'm not testing the restart yet. I just want a fresh and complete run with a new set of parameters. I thought that putting a new parameter with an unique value would flag spring batch that I want a new execution.

Comment: If you get JobExecutionAlreadyRunningException you have to stop it first with JobOperator.stop

Comment: Removing the incrementer solved the original problem. The other issue I mentioned in the comments of this answer was caused because all my parameters were non indentifying. They were just regular spring boot parameters. When I added the first identifying parameter the things start working as expected.